# Spring boot how to have Thymeleaf web page and REST API with different authentications Schemes

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-security, jwt, thymeleaf

Like the question said, how we can configure Spring Security to have form authentication for the Thymeleaf web page part of the project, and JWT authentication for the REST API part of the project?, because we like to have both projects on the same container and not to have to resource to external Tomcat Application Server to have the same Security Config (SSL, Ciphers, Certificates, ETC.).

So far we don't found how to do it, but if you can have a Thymeleaf and REST API on the same project i think it is possible to configure Spring Security to have to ways of authentication on the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have this behavior by adding two `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` beans as follows:

- @Order(1) - /api/** protected by basic auth, in your case JWT
  authentication.
- @Order(2) - /website/** protected by form login, in your case 
  Thymeleaf login.

View docs for [Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Security-2.0#restoring-separation-of-basic-auth-for-actuator-endpoints-but-something-else-for-user-defined-endpoints) and sample code [here](https://github.com/mageddo/java-examples/tree/6a7dd2b426f17a1c5ebab1552f25e8c62d2d9aee/spring-security/basic-and-form-auth-together).

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class ApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("API_USER")
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/website/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll()
            ;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help